# How to limit searching characters if I use LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, string, search, character

I have a function that returns duplicated (occur 2 or more times) characters in text. I do it with LINQ:

```
 public char[] linq(string text)
    {            
        char[] result = text
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .Select(g => g.Key).ToArray();
        return result;
    }
```

But this way returns duplicated occurrences of all characters in the text (string). How to limit searching, if I want to search just English alphabet characters: abcdefghi....etc.
Thanx for help.

Comment: Thanx for all but answer that solves my problem was deleted( By the way two first answer are helpful. Thanx a lot.

Comment: I deleted my answer when I noticed that you mentioned only wanting characters from the *English* alphabet. [`Char.IsLetter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w.aspx)  matches characters from any category of Unicode letter.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed it also. But it could be using also, so thank you anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
linq("and a rhino 11", new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' }); // result: { 'a' }

public char[] linq(string text, char[] limitChars)
{
    char[] result = text
        .Where( c => limitChars.Contains(c))
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
        .Select(g => g.Key)
        .ToArray();
    return result;
}
```

This solution only applies if you need to limit the character range to a *configurable* list.

Note that the `char.IsLetter()` method will allow characters from other alphabets (i.e. cyrillic, greek, etc.) to pass as well, so this might not be ideal.

Next best thing w/o passing a configurable list is @Femaref's solution imo explicitly using the character codes of the English alphabet - this might work best in your particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
    char[] result = text
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1 && (g.Key >= 65 && g.Key <= 122))
        .Select(g => g.Key).ToArray();
```

**Update from comments:**

```
    char[] result = text
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1 && ((g.Key >= 65 && g.Key <= 90) || (g.Key >= 97 && g.Key <= 122)))
        .Select(g => g.Key).ToArray();
```

Comment: Just a side note but you would have to break up the char code range to exclude the special chars within the 65-122 range. eg. "c >= 65 && c <= 90) || (c >= 97 && c <= 122)"

Comment: oh, are there special chars between the groups? didn't realize that, just glanced over it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like char.IsLetter() is what you want: [char.IsLetter()](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2808.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need.

// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter.aspx

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(linq(@"szuizu_4156424324_hjvlahsjlvhlkd_&&§"));
    Console.Read();
}

public static char[] linq(string text)
{
    char[] result = text
                .Where(Char.IsLetter)
                .GroupBy(x => x)
                .Where(g =>g.Count() > 1)
                .Select(g => g.Key).ToArray();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanx, I've solved my question already. Aren't you user, that has write something like "just add Where(Char.IsLetter) before your GroupBy" and delete that answer?

Comment: Thanx it's good method, but it allows to all Unicode letters. In my case I need more narrow solution, b/c I need to search duplicated characters within English alphabet.

Comment: Thats true, you can use "c >= 65 && c <= 90) || (c >= 97 && c <= 122)" instead as Femaref pointed out.